# Find $x$ in this series of circle!

Tags: mathematics

[image]

I truly have no idea what should I do. The only relation I could find is, on circle $2$, $38$ is equal to $19\times2$ (from circle one), and on circle $3$, $72$ is equal to $18\times4$ (from circle one). It was a multiple choice about a question in series of arithmetics, and the choices were $11, 12, 13, 14,$ and $15$. I just couldn't prove any of the choices.

I didn't know where the source was from, a friend sent it to mine.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! If you had gotten this puzzle from somewhere else, please state where you've gotten it from!

Comment: @Marchotridyo  Please accept the answer if it is right.

Answer (score 10):

Solution:

> 15

Explanation:

> I noticed that the sum of numbers in the lower parts results in a number that is one more than or equal to a perfect square. 
>  I think the number at the top is the root of that square increased by one.